# Remove 'Date' rows having any 'NA' in the 'Value' column

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I have a data frame with multiple time series . I would like to remove all data in date that have NA values.

The data frame looks as follows,

```
Date    Time    Value
1/1/2014    0:00    30
1/1/2014    1:00    20
1/1/2014    2:00    12
1/1/2014    3:00    NA
    .   
    .   
    .   
1/1/2014    23:00   23
2/1/2014    0:00    12
2/1/2014    1:00    23
2/1/2014    2:00    34
2/1/2014    3:00    43
    .   
    .   
    .   
2/1/2014    23:00   30
3/1/2014    0:00    34
3/1/2014    1:00    NA
3/1/2014    2:00    NA
3/1/2014    3:00    23
    .   
    .   
    .   
3/1/2014    23:00   45
```

I would remove all data in date that have NA values so that the data frame look as follows,

```
Date    Time    Value
2/1/2014    0:00    12
2/1/2014    1:00    23
2/1/2014    2:00    34
2/1/2014    3:00    43
    .   
    .   
    .   
2/1/2014    23:00   30
```

Comment: Ok, my bad, it is not a duplicate. Here you want to remove all rows, for which at least one row was NA.

Comment: It's not a duplicate.

Comment: I reopened as it is not a duplicate of that. All values need to be removed from group if one is NA

Comment: @RonakShah - the question is not about removing rows where any value is missing, it is about removing whole groups where the date is ever associated with a missing value.

Comment: From the duplicated link : `library(dplyr);
df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  filter(!any(is.na(Value)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably many ways to do this, but here's one. Find the unique `Date` values associated with a missing `Value`, and remove those rows from the final selection:

```
dat[!dat$Date %in% unique(dat[is.na(dat$Value),"Date"]),]

       Date  Time Value
6  2/1/2014  0:00    12
7  2/1/2014  1:00    23
8  2/1/2014  2:00    34
9  2/1/2014  3:00    43
10 2/1/2014 23:00    30
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear about the wording in the question.   If this is meant to remove 'date' rows having `any` 'NA' in the 'Value' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[!any(is.na(Value))] , Date]
#       Date  Time Value
#1: 2/1/2014  0:00    12
#2: 2/1/2014  1:00    23
#3: 2/1/2014  2:00    34
#4: 2/1/2014  3:00    43
#5: 2/1/2014 23:00    30
```

Comment: I think they want to remove whole `Date`s where any `Value` is `NA` for that date. I.e. `1/1` and `3/1` seem to have been removed totally.

Comment: Thanks for comment.  @akrun You're correct.

Comment: @akrun Please, can you check your answer? I've tried it with OP's data but it doesn't remove a single row.

Comment: @UweBlock The OP said `Thanks for comment. @akrun You're correct.`

Comment: @akrun Would you mind to post the result of your code then, please?

Comment: @UweBlock  The question title is `Remove all data in date that have NA values` I don't find any NA in the data you updated in the OP's post.  If this is a group by operation, then I updated the post

Comment: There are NA values in the `Value` column. Please, re-read the [comment of thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317737/remove-all-data-in-date-that-have-na-values#comment77597572_45317806) and see what the OP has posted as expected result.

Comment: @UweBlock Updated the post if that is what the OP meant

Comment: Thank you, @akrun But please check the result of `df[complete.cases(df$Date),]`. It has no effect as there are no `NA` in the `Date` column.